# Delete Column if Header does not Contain

Tags: vba, excel

The following code works if one word is used, although, I would like it to look for two words.  So if column header, found in row 3, does not contain "Homer" or "Marge", delete that entire column.

```
Sub DontDelete()

Dim currentColumn As Integer

'Delete if the cell doesn't contain "Homer" OR "Marge"
If InStr(3, _
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(3, currentColumn).Value, _
       "Homer", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

End If

End Sub
```

How can I incorporate `OR "Marge"` into this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `And`

```
If InStr(3, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(3, currentColumn).Value, _
       "Homer", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 And InStr(3, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(3, currentColumn).Value, _
       "Marge", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
End If
```

Comment: I've should have come up with this ... slipping lately :).  This worked the trick.  Thanks.